# How to detect if mouse is pressed

Tags: vb.net, mouse

In VB.NET how do you detect if a mouse button is currently pressed?

ex:

```
If Mouse.Button1.IsHeldDown Then
     ...
End If
```

I would like to know if there is a better way than creating seperate mouse up and mouse down events.

Comment: Always mention what kind of gui class library you use.  In Winforms you get it from the Control.MouseButtons property.  In WPF from the Mouse.LeftButton property.  Etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Windows Forms:

`MouseButtons.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Right)`

This will return `True` if the right mouse button is currently being pressed.

For any mouse button being pressed you could do something like this:

```
If Not MouseButtons.HasFlags(MouseButtons.None) Then '...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If System.Windows.Input.Mouse.LeftButton.HasFlag(MouseButtonState.Pressed) OR System.Windows.Input.Mouse.RigthButton.HasFlag(MouseButtonState.Pressed) Then
       Your Code
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

on the `mouseclick` event add this

```
        If Not (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left And e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) Then MsgBox("mouse is up")
```

Comment: Wow...this is completely wrong.  Binary AND and Binary OR is needed.  If (e.Button And (MouseButtons.Left Or MouseButtons.Right) != MouseButtons.None) Then ' which mention both buttons being pressed.  If (e.Button != MouseButtons.None) Then will tell if any button is not pressed.

Comment: the user wants to check whene the button is up

Comment: @K3rnel31 Why do you think so?