# Visual Basic 2010 Detecting MouseUp in MouseDown event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, mouseevent

I have a project I'm working on that involves looping code when the mouse is down and stopping the code when the mouse becomes up again. The issue I have now seems to be that it automatically assumes that the mouse is down because it is running MouseDown code, or at least that's how I translate it to be.

```
Private Sub picDisplay_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles pictureBox1.MouseDown    
isMouseDown = True
        Me.Text = "Down"
        bg = New Bitmap("base.jpg")
        picDisplay.Image = bg
        moX = MousePosition.X
        moY = MousePosition.Y
        Do
            'insert a ton of code here
            If System.Windows.Input.Mouse.LeftButton.HasFlag(MouseButtonState.Pressed) Then isMouseDown = False
        Loop Until isMouseDown = False
End Sub
```

Things I've tried include adding a MouseUp event, using a timer, running a detector, and used the `Case MouseButtons` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015791/vb-net-detect-if-mouse-is-up) post interchangeably all with no results.

Kind comments are appreciated!

---

Edit:

Okay, I've got this, but the current issue is the Object Already In Use that I get from drawing my image as part of the code:

```
 Private Sub BackgroundWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles moveWindow.DoWork
        bg = New Bitmap("base.jpg")
        picDisplay.Image = bg
        moX = MousePosition.X
        moY = MousePosition.Y
        Do
            mcX = MousePosition.X
            mcY = MousePosition.Y
            Dim movementX As Integer = moX - mcX
            Dim movementY As Integer = moY - mcY
            displayX = displayX - movementX
            displayY = displayY - movementY
                     'If displayX <= 0 And displayY <= 0 Then --- This isn't working right now, but I know why and I'll fix it later
            picDisplay.CreateGraphics.DrawImage(bg, displayX, displayY, bg.Width, bg.Height)
        If moveWindow.CancellationPending Then Exit Do
        Application.DoEvents()
        Loop Until isMouseDown = False

End Sub
```

The issue seems to be that it tries to draw the image a second time, but it still hasn't finished drawing it the first time I'm not sure how to fix this, but I'll be trying a few things that I know of in the meantime.

Comment: What does your Visual Basic code, that you posted, have to do with the C language (you added a C language tag).  Are you calling C language functions?

Comment: Sorry, got confused with my languages.

Comment: You are calling DoEvents in a BackgroundWorker?  You are drawing in a background thread?  Big no-no's.  Get rid of the BackgroundWorker and just use a Timer.  Stop the time on the MouseUp event.

Comment: I already tried a timer and it failed. If you have an possible answer, please express it as an answer, not a comment shaming the above answer.

Comment: Since you are using a BackgroundWorker, you shouldn't need a DoEvents call. I think that you should only update PicDisplay from UpdateProgress so that it occurs in the GUI's thread.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, since it made no difference with the `Object Already in Use` error

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. To test, create a new WinForms project. Add 2 labels and a button. Then add this code:

```
Dim mouseIsDown As Boolean

Private Sub Button1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseDown
    Dim counter As Integer
    mouseIsDown = True
    Label1.Text = "Mouse is down"
    Do
        counter += 1
        Label2.Text = CStr(counter)
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop While mouseIsDown
    Label1.Text = "Mouse is up"
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseUp
    mouseIsDown = False
End Sub
```

Comment: The issue with this part is that the `HasFlag` doesn't really exist. I probably should have taken it out.

Comment: I think it depends on the .Net Framework version. @CalebSalyards Did you get it to work?

Comment: No, it won't let me run it at all because of the `HasFlag` issue.

Comment: I agree. I had did as web search and found msdn doc that was similar to you mouse code. In VS2013 I couldn't get it to work either. I would try adding a member-level Boolean called mouseDown. In the mouse down event handler, set it to true. Add a handler for mouse up and in there set it to false. Loop until mouseDown = False. You'll have to do a `Application.DoEvents()` in your loop.

Comment: Okay, it keeps coming up with an "Object Already In Use" error, which apparently has to do with trying to draw the image a second time before it's done drawing it the first time. I'll look into fixing it myself tomorrow, but if someone happens to know a quick easy fix (maybe the `Synclock` command I have yet to delve into) I would be happy to hear about it.

Comment: Okay, I'll add this as part of my question in an "Update"

Answer (score 0):

OK first off, in your Form's designer view, add a BackgroundWorker to your form - it should appear under the form like a timer does. Click it to show the properties on the right of the visual studio window. Change **WorkerSupportsCancellation** from **False** to **True**.

Replace your code above with this, remembering to add your code into the loop in the **BackgroundWorker1_DoWork** sub.

```
Private Sub picDisplay_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles pictureBox1.MouseDown
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
        If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
            If BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation Then
                BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Me.Text = "Down"
        bg = New Bitmap("base.jpg")
        picDisplay.Image = bg
        moX = MousePosition.X
        moY = MousePosition.Y
        Do
            'insert a ton of code here
            'Don't delete the line below
            If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending Then Exit Do
        Loop
    End Sub
```

What happens now is that when you click press down on the mouse button, the **MouseDown** event fires and this launches the **BackgroundWorker1_DoWork** code which contains your code and also checks the **BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending** flag to see if it is true and then exits the loop if it is.

When you let go of the mouse button, the **MouseUp** code runs and checks if the BackgroundWorker is actually running and also if it supports cancellation. If it is running and supports cancellation then it runs the **CancelAsync** method which sets the **CancellatonPending** flag to True. Meanwhile you code is busy looping around. When the loop gets to the point where it checks the **CancellationPending** flag, it exits the loop and the background thread terminates.

You *might* have problems running the code in the background depending on what it interacts with, but give it a go, you might end up lucky. If you do get problems, have a go at solving them (Google is your friend). And if you're still stuck come back and see us :O)