# Catch Datagridview error when multi select row failed

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a Datagridview with Multiselect to True.
Everything works fine but i have discovered a small issue.

Data are binded every minutes automaticaly.

**Issue example:**

**First bind (total : 20 rows):** user select row number 20 and keep mouse down

**Second bind (total : 10 rows):** if user move selection to row 8 there is an error

I understand this error, on second bind, row index 20 disappear. But i don't find how to catch this error or prevent it.

Thanks for your help

My test code without database connection but same issue:

```
               If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then

                    DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()

                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add({False, "test", "", "", ""})
                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add({False, "test", "", "", ""})
                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add({False, "test", "", "", ""})
                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add({False, "test", "", "", ""})
                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add({False, "test", "", "", ""})
                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add({False, "test", "", "", ""})
                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add({False, "test", "", "", ""})
                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add({False, "test", "", "", ""})
                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add({False, "test", "", "", ""})

                    DataGridView2.Sort(DataGridView2.Columns(1), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    DataGridView2.ClearSelection()

                ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then

                    DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()

                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add({False, "test2", "", "", ""})
                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add({False, "test2", "", "", ""})
                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add({False, "test2", "", "", ""})
                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add({False, "test2", "", "", ""})


                    DataGridView2.Sort(DataGridView2.Columns(1), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    DataGridView2.ClearSelection()

                End If
```

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
  HResult=0x80131502
  Message=La valeur '23' n'est pas valide pour 'indexStart'. 'indexStart' doit être inférieur ou égal à 10.
Nom du paramètre : indexStart
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.GetPreviousRow(Int32 indexStart, DataGridViewElementStates includeFilter)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowSelectMouseMove(HitTestInfo hti)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 81

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.GetPreviousRow(int, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewElementStates)
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowSelectMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.HitTestInfo)
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr, int, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr)
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr, int, int)
```

Comment: You can handle the `UnhandledException` event of the application and look for the specifics of that exception.

Comment: To prevent the error, you should post the code that generates it, there's something wrong with it. You're probably storing index values that are no more valid after an update. Reset these values and clear any selection when the Control is updated.

Comment: Maybe you should just avoid modifying the data in the grid if the user has the mouse button down. Defer the rebind until the user has released the mouse button. Problem solved!

Comment: I have posted my code thanks

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution :

Before each bind :
`If Not MouseButtons.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left) Then`

[How to detect if mouse is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015791/how-to-detect-if-mouse-is-pressed/46765992)

Thanks to jmcilhinney  for the easier idea